# Can you demand un-attribution under your name with content you licensed under CC-BY-SA?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

If I previously released content under CC-BY-SA 3.0, can I demand my name be removed from attribution as in the case of no longer wanted to be associated with it?

The [FAQ has this to say](https://creativecommons.org/faq/)

> While you cannot revoke the license, **CC licenses do provide a mechanism for licensors to ask that others using their material remove the attribution information.** You should think carefully before choosing a Creative Commons license.

What is that mechanism and do I have that right?

Comment: You do understand what attribution is, yes? And that CC-BY-SA **requires it by definition**, yes?

Comment: @Nij updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is language, but not a mechanism, covering this. Section 3(a)(3) of [version 4 licenses](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode#s3a1Ai) says

> If requested by the Licensor, You must remove any of the information
>   required by Section 3(a)(1)(A) to the extent reasonably practicable.

If you become aware of a person using your material and attributing you, and you want the attribution removed, you would accordingly notify them (somehow), and they are required to remove the offending material. The removable informations includes:

> i.    identification of the creator(s) of the Licensed Material and
>   any others designated to receive attribution, in any reasonable manner
>   requested by the Licensor (including by pseudonym if designated);
>
> ii.    a copyright notice;
>
> iii.    a notice that refers to this Public License;
>
> iv.    a notice that refers to the disclaimer of warranties;
>
> v.    a URI or hyperlink to the Licensed Material to the extent
>   reasonably practicable;

Comment: I never followed up with this, but of course this content was on StackExchange. I was able to invoke my right under this clause and have a deleted-question unattributed (because users can no longer delete questions). If you come here because your content is on StackExchange, you can write them at team@stackexchange.com and invoke this right.